# Header Background Color Isn't Fixed on Page

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem on one particular page of my website that I'm working on. On all my other pages, my header is fixed and when the page scrolls up the header (with logo and navigation menu and background color) stay on top. On this one particular page, the navigation menu and logo stay fixed, but the page seems to be scrolling over the background color.

I know that it's something I've done with the grid and/or section on the page, but I can't figure out how to fix it. This is for a class project and with the class being online, I've taught myself a lot by using the web (the book and presentation materials were not very good at breaking down and explaining.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-nyc.css">
        <title>NYC MUSH: Behind the Veil</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>


<body>
      <!-- Header Section -->
      <header>
        <img src="images/logo_02.png">
    </header>

    <!-- Hero Banner -->
    <div id="hero-image">
        <p class="hero-text"> ~ Cast ~</p>
        </div>

       <!-- Navigation Menu -->   
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="world.html">World</a></li>
            <li><a href="cast.html">Cast</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="join.html">Join</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
        

<!-- Main Section Text -->
<!-- Grid for Cast Members -->
<section id="cast-page">
<div class="grid-container">
    <!-- Grid items for cast members -->
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <img src="images/default-headshot.jpg" alt="Player Character">
      <h3>Name</h3>
      <p>Face Claim: </p>
      <p>Race: </p>
      <p>Faction: </p>
    </div>
     
    
      
  </div>
  </section>
      

      <!-- Footer Section -->
      <div id="footer"><footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 NYC MUSH: Behind the Veil. All rights reserved. <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="https://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/4.0/80x15.png" /></a><br />This work is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License</a>.</p>
      </footer>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
/*Begin Style for Mobile Viewport */

header {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
 }


  
/* CSS Header */
header {
    background-color: #0e0c36;
    color: #b6c5c9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
}

header img {
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
  
/* CSS Navigation */
 
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline; 
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px; 
  }
  
  nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b6c5c9;
  }
  
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #bbb7a3;
    color: #0e0c36;
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }

#hero-image {

    /* Background Styles */
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('../images/nycskybanner01.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

    /* Sizing */
    height: 275px;

    /* Display */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: #cef2f9;
}

#hero-image02 {

  /* Background Styles */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('../images/nycskybanner02.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

  /* Sizing */
  height: 350px;

  /* Display */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.hero-text {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Grid Layout for Cast Page */
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 2%;
  }
  
  /* Style for each portrait item */
  .grid-item {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
 .grid-item h3 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 }

  /* Style for the portrait image */
  .grid-item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    transition: filter 0.5s ease;
  }

 
.grid-item img:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

I've tried adding a z-index to the header in the css.

I've tried putting the grid into a div and into a section.